# push data securely from lambda to elastic

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-elasticsearch

I have this policy that accepts requests from a single assumed role. When I try to push data from lambda, I get an access denied error.
If I open the access to elastic server using this line, then it will work as expected.

> ```
>     "AWS": "*"
> ```

But it is not secure. How do I push data from lambda to elastic service that is restricted to Cognito users?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::51346970xxxx:assumed-role/document-search-CognitoAuthorizedRole-LZWR058L66O8/CognitoIdentityCredentials"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:51346970xxxx:domain/documentsearchapp/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the following policy to your lambda (without the ```Principal``` line):
```{```
```"Version": "2012-10-17",```
```"Statement": [```
```{```
```"Effect": "Allow",```
```"Action": "es:*",```
```"Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:51346970xxxx:domain/documentsearchapp/*"```
```}```
```]```
```}```

And then you allow the lambda execution just to your Cognito users? I had the same need here and I managed to solve that problem like that!